# Is it possible to store timestamp in avro and read it back without any conversion?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, avro

Trying to store the timestamp values in hive using Avro file format , As we don't have native support to timestamp data types in hive trying with logical columns.

**Sample :**

```
CREATE TABLE avro_table_willi (a string, b long )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'avro.schema.literal'='{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "my_record",
    "fields": [
      {"name": "a", "type": "int"},
      {"name": "b", "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis" }

          ]}');
```

can anyone help me to understand is it possible to store the timestamp values and read it back as timestamp using logicaltype data type in hive for avro.

I can understand the different approach to store the timestamp into bigint / string while reading we can convert.

But looking for the help on logicaltype.

Comment: Yeah I uploaded an avro object file that contained a record field with logicalType timestamp-millis, and when I query the resulting table in hive, I get a long, no recognition that it is a timestamp... :(